# Connect iPhone via network for debugging in Xcode 13 not working

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, wifi

I know this question is pretty popular since this feature has been introduced by Apple. But it is still one of the most questionable things in Xcode (at least to me).

[image]

**Using:**:

- Xcode 13.3,
- iPhone 13 (iOS 15.4)
- the Mac machine and the device have the same Wi-Fi network.

**Tried**:

- Unpair / pair with USB
- Turned off/on WiFi on both Mac and iPhone
- Enabled the "Connect via network" box
- Restarted Xcode and iPhone
- Restarted Network settings on iPhone
- Conneting with IP

**The result**:

- There is no a network icon next to the device
- Device debugging working only via USB

**Question**:

- How to connect? Maybe I have to check something extra?

It will be super cool if somebody can describe the maximum options that can be checked in this case, I think it could be useful for everyone.